# When does $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^n+n^2}{3^n+n^3}z^n$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

For what values of $z \in \mathbb{C}$ does the following series converge:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^n+n^2}{3^n+n^3}z^n\quad ?$$

Comment: I bet there are some missing parentheses?

Comment: Do you mean $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^n+n^2}{3^n+n^3}\,z^n\:?$$And as with your other question, what have you tried?

Comment: Are you familiar with the ratio test?

Comment: nour: Why are you vandalizing your own question?

Comment: this was by mistake. I thought that I added a new question.

Comment: @nour: I have put your original question back. Please ask a new question [by going here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) (or go to the "Ask Question" button on the upper right of the site).

Comment: Try using the root test, combined with the fact that $n^k/a^n \to 0$ for $k \ge 0$ and $a > 1$ as n gets large.

Comment: Hint: note that $\dfrac{2^n+n^2}{3^n+n^3} - \dfrac{2^n}{3^n} = O\left(\dfrac{n^3}{3^n}\right)$.  Your series converges whenever $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\dfrac{2z}{3}\right)^n$ converges.

Answer (score 2):

You're given

$$f(z)=\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^n+n^2}{3^n+n^3}z^n$$

A sensible solution would be using Cauchy's Root test. We want to find

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{2^n+n^2}{3^n+n^3}\right)^{1/n} =$$

$$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac 2 3\left(\frac{1+n^2/2^n}{1+n^3/3^n}\right)^{1/n} =$$

$$=\frac 2 3\left(\frac{1+0}{1+0}\right)^{0}=\frac 2 3 $$

Then the sum converges for $|z|<\dfrac 3 2 $

Comment: I think also that for z=$\frac{-3}{2}$ the series converges by Abel's test. right?

Comment: we can take $a_k=(-1)^n$ and $b_k=a_n$

Comment: I think also that we can have convergence by Abel's test for $z=\frac{-3}{2}$

Comment: @nour I see you have asked another question which addresses $z=\tfrac {-3} 2$, but I just wanted to point out that the criteria for [Abel's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_test) are not satisfied with the series $a_k = (-1)^n=b_k$.