# determine whether this series converges for this value of z

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Does $$f(z)=\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^n+n^2}{3^n+n^3}z^n$$ converge for   $z=\frac{-3}{2}$?

Comment: In general, text should not go between dollars.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: no, I'm studying for GRE test.... I'm trying using Abel's test but I need to clarify this answer

Comment: it would be better if you put your solution here and ask for the clarification

Comment: To be clear, this is a subquestion of the [OP's previous queston](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156280/when-does-sum-n-0-infty-frac2nn23nn3zn-converge)

Answer (score 3):

Hint (assuming this is homework):

Consider the terms $$\frac{2^n+n^2}{3^n+n^3}\left(\frac{-3}{2}\right)^n.$$

Can you find the limit of this expression as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: I Know that this series converges for $|z|<\frac{3}{2}$ by ratio test...and diverges for $z=\frac{3}{2}$ using limit of $\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$.but what about $z=\frac{-3}{2}$

Comment: Then ask: Can the series converge if the terms do not converge to zero?

Comment: so series diverges for $z=\frac{-3}{2}$

Comment: It certainly cannot converge.

Comment: Thanks for your hints...this was helpful

Answer (score 1):

$$ \frac{2^n + n^2}{3^n + n^3} z^n  = \frac{2^n}{3^n + n^3} z^n + \frac{n^2}{3^n + n^3} z^n $$
$$ \frac{n^2}{3^n + n^3} z^n < n^2 \left ( \frac{z}{3} \right )^n  = \frac{n^2 }{(-2)^n } \text{ Which converges from Ratio test }$$
$$ \frac{2^n}{3^n + n^3} z^n = \left ( \frac{2}{3} z\right )^n \frac{1}{1 + \frac{n^3}{3^n}}  \text{ which is } (-1)^n \text{ for } n \rightarrow \infty \text{ (It does not converge) } $$